# Typescript error while node_modules is excluded

Tags: typescript

This is my tsconfig

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es2017",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "lib": [
         "es7",
         "es2017"
      ]
   },
   "include": [
      "src/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
   ]
}
```

When I try to build my ts files I get

```
> tsc

node_modules/@types/better-sqlite3/index.d.ts(14,55): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/better-sqlite3/index.d.ts(14,79): error TS1005: '=' expected.
```

What is causing this problem and how can I fix it? I mentioned node_modules in the exclude

Comment: Hi, from Microsoft's wiki about typescript, it looks that excluded files will still get included if they're related to a referenced module. It is better explained in [this link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-a-file-in-the-exclude-list-still-picked-up-by-the-compiler). By using the command "tsc --traceResolution | grep sqlite" you should be able to check why files from that folder are still included in your project (there may be some reference elsewhere).

Comment: I am using the module but I do not understand why I get the above error when building